# [MTB ]How much can my bike endure?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, shifter

I recently bought a (Mountainbike) Bergamont Revox 3.0 and I'm concerned that I'm not taking proper care of it.

I want to know if I can, for example, ride down a flight of stairs or switch the gears while I'm riding up a steep hill.

I clean it regularly where I can, and it's currently sitting in the basement (due to weather) anyway.

But the question is, how much "rider-abuse" can my bike withstand ?

Comment: Big range.  Clean is not going to make it stronger.  Switch gear up hill is kind of expected.   If you can stay upright it is pretty darn hard to break even a cheap bike.   Voting to close as too broad and opinion.

Comment: i thought moist dirt and mud could potentially corrupt some material on my bike, especially in the gears, also your're saying that I get a little rough to my bike ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like a freeride or dirt jump bike. Ride it until it breaks, then get a stronger one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/35263/how-much-of-a-bruising-can-a-mtb-take

Comment: FWIW, prior to indexed shifting you could not practically shift while under load -- even on level ground you had to ease off pedaling.  Indexed shifting changed that, but you still need to use some care when shifting under load -- the main danger is a jammed/broken chain, but you also cause the drive components to wear faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bikes break because they've been either mistreated or not cared for.  Riding a bike down stairs should be okay provided you don't fall off or catch anything.... that's what a MTB is built for.

Proper care and maintenance keeps everything working, so lubrication and washing off mud/silt etc will keep the bike functioning.  Storing your bike inside out of the weather is the single best thing you can do to preserve it and extend its life.

If your question was about a road bike or a hybrid/commuter, I'd say stairs would be outside the normal usage for such a frame.

Finally, every bike needs to change gear while going uphill.  The only trick is timing, to get the chain to move cogs/chainrings while at the top of the stroke where the pressure is less.  If you're changing gear with the pedal cranks horizontal then that's sub-optimal and bad for the transmission.

This question is likely to generate various opinions.

Comment: thanks for the answer

are there any particular brands of maintaining equipment that you're recommending ?

Comment: @zython - sorry we don't recommend brands here - the internet is global and if I recommend "fred dagg's gumboot grease" then it won't be available in other countries.    Global suppliers like Park are pretty good, but a spanner is a spanner anywhere.

Comment: alright got it, cheers mate